# Проблемы с JSON.stringify() и JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

Здравствуйте. Для примера возьмем JSON

```
{  
       "ID":"1111",
       "title":"Example",
       "baseConfigs":[  
          {  
             "ID":"1444",
             "title":"Example 2"
          }
       ]
    }
```

JSON.stringify() вернет следующее

```
{"ID":"1111","title":"Exapmle","baseConfigs":"[{\"ID\": \"1444\", \"title\": \"Tripp TrappВ® Chair\"}]"}
```

После него пытаясь распарсить с JSON.parse(), получаем

```
{
    "ID":"1111",
    "title":"Exapmle",
    "baseConfigs":"[{"ID": "1444", "title": "Example 2"}]"
}
```

Проблема в том, что JSON.stringify() из массива делает строку, а JSON.parse() так же видит массив только как строку, а не как массив

Есть варианты как это исправить? Спасибо

Comment: JSON.stringify() не сделает из первого второе. Скорее всего вы ошибаетесь и никакого массива у вас нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего ошибка в применении [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Приведенный код работает именно так как и требуется.

```js
var obj = {
  "ID": "1111",
  "title": "Example",
  "baseConfigs": [{
    "ID": "1444",
    "title": "Example 2"
  }]
};
var stringified = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
document.write('<pre>', stringified, '</pre>');

var parsed = JSON.parse(stringified);
document.write('Type of parsed baseConfigs: ', typeof parsed.baseConfigs,
  '<br/>Is parsed baseConfigs instance of Array? ', parsed.baseConfigs instanceof Array);
```

Причины ошибки могут быть следующие:

1. В начальном объект *baseConfigs* изначально строка
2. `JSON.stringify` был применен сначала к *baseConfigs* и затем ко всему объекту.

Comment: возможно странные конфликты с React. Да, один и тот же код действительно везде работает, но в реакте массив в скобки оборачивает.

Comment: @Wepster, очевидно надо привести воспроизводимый пример, на данный момент, не зная что и как происходит в коде, кроме того, что все должно работать, ничего нельзя сказать

Answer (score 0):

Вы ошибаетесь.

```js
var originalData = {
  "ID": "1111",
  "title": "Example",
  "baseConfigs": [{
    "ID": "1444",
    "title": "Example 2"
  }]
}

var stringData = JSON.stringify(originalData);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(stringData);

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(jsonData.baseConfigs));
console.log(jsonData.baseConfigs[0].title);
```